# Sparse sets in Pyomo for representing arc / edge sets in graph/network models

Tags: python, networkx, pyomo, directed-graph, undirected-graph

I have no clue how  to define an edge set in `pyomo`.

I have a *very-low-density* (sparse) network (aka graph), where the number of edges is much less than a fully-connected graph.

I want to define an edge set so I can construct constraints  that have to do with the edges. However I cannot wrap my mind around what pyomo expects me to do, and everything I do results in incredibly-unhelpful error messages.

```
import pyomo
import pyomo.environ as pe
edges = [(0,1),(0,2),(1,2),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)]

model = pe.ConcreteModel()
model.E = pe.Set(initialize=lambda _,i : edges[i]) # Edge set
```

The above code throws the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Joey\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\block.py", line 568, in __setattr__
    self.add_component(name, val)
  File "C:\Users\Joey\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\block.py", line 1008, in add_component
    val.construct(data)
  File "C:\Users\Joey\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\sets.py", line 1221, in construct
    self.add(val)
  File "C:\Users\Joey\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\sets.py", line 821, in add
    self._verify(tmp)
  File "C:\Users\Joey\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\sets.py", line 772, in _verify
    raise ValueError("The value="+str(element)+" is a tuple for set="+self.name+", which has dimen="+str(self.dimen))
ValueError: The value=(0, 2) is a tuple for set=E, which has dimen=1
```

A given edge is completely identified by a tuple. The edge connecting node `0` and node `1` should be `(0,1)`. That tuple should be its identifier. A list of such identifiers has dimension 1. So I'm not sure what `pyomo` expects me to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that `dim` is the dimensionality of the set itself. `dimen` is the number of elements that each set element must contain, not the dimensionality of the set. Pyomo assumes as default that `dimen=1`, which means that Set will not accept a tuple as a set element because it has more than one element. Setting `dimen=None` disables this argument checking.

Thus one way is to pass a list of edges for `initialize`, with dimension 2 or `None`.

```
model.E = pe.Set(initialize=edges, dimen=2)
```

The set constructor does not know the number of elements so this doesn't actually work:

```
model.E = pe.Set(initialize=lambda _,i: edges[i], dimen=2) # Edge set
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Joey\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\block.py", line 568, in __setattr__
    self.add_component(name, val)
  File "C:\Users\Joey\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\block.py", line 1008, in add_component
    val.construct(data)
  File "C:\Users\Joey\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\sets.py", line 1223, in construct
    val = apply_indexed_rule(self, self.initialize, self._parent(), ctr)
  File "C:\Users\Joey\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\misc.py", line 61, in apply_indexed_rule
    return rule(model, index)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So you would have to use

```
model.E = pe.Set(initialize=
    (edges[i] for i in range(len(edges))), dimen=2) # Edge set
```